# Openlayers v3.13.1, Construct Layers From PHP/Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm In a Map proyect made with Openlayers. I'm realy, realy new in JS, AJAX and Openlayers

I need to build layers in the map, I have DATA in Mysql dbase, need to do something like this:

```
 var *layername* = new ol.layer.Vector({ // *layername* need to have layername came from php file
              visible: false,
              title: 'puntos', // Here I need to parse a result from mysql data that has the layers names that I need
              source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                      url: 'file.php?layer='+, // plus layername
                      projection: 'EPSG:3857',
              }),
              style: new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                          anchor: [10, 26],
                          anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
                          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                          src: "./img/marquita_naranja.png" // this has to came from php too
                    })),
              })
new ol.layer.Group({
                    title: 'Capas',
                    layers: lcapas, // I need to build this from an Array with Mysql reasult
          }),
```

Note: I have, for now, five Layers to parse in, maybe a loop... I mean a dynamically build of that five result, need to build something like this:

```
new ol.layer.Group({
                    title: 'Capas',
                    layers: [
                               new ol.layer.Vector({
              visible: false,
              title: 'Ciudades y Plazas',
              source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                      url: 'consulta_puntos.php?capa=Ciudades y Plazas',
                      projection: 'EPSG:3857',
              }),
              style: new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                          anchor: [10, 26],
                          anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
                          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                          src: "./img/marquita_verde.png"
                    })),
              }),
          }),
          new ol.layer.Vector({
              visible: false,
              title: 'Museos',
              source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                      url: 'consulta_puntos.php?capa=Museos',
                      projection: 'EPSG:3857',
              }),
              style: new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                          anchor: [10, 26],
                          anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
                          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                          src: "./img/marquita_amarilla.png"
                    })),
              }),
          }),
          new ol.layer.Vector({
              visible: false,
              title: 'Lagos',
              source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                      url: 'consulta_puntos.php?capa=Lagos',
                      projection: 'EPSG:3857',
              }),
              style: new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                          anchor: [10, 26],
                          anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
                          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                          src: "./img/marquita_azul.png"
                    })),
              }),
          }),
       ]
```

burn my eyes search in google something that help me, but all that i found uses AJAX and with the result writes in a HTML objet, I don't need this....

Sorry if this is a very noob question, and very sorry about my english this isn't my principal language

PD.: Thanks in advance, hope someone can help with this

Comment: mmmm.... Ok, Maybe it's imposible... and needs to add layers manually....  the idea was: the user can create layers and Openlayers3 give them from Database.... but i'm still search in all places and don't find nothing,,,, It's posible do something like this?.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this right now: layers['layer_'+layername] = new ol.layer.Vector({ ...... source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({ ...php Json result.... }) });...... the object form ok... but I don't know how to add this to the map.. ajax gives me layername